# Why does the compiler say "statement expected, but expression of type '<x>' found"?

Tags: delphi

I googled around and found a way to set the mouse cursor position in Delphi.
Here is my code example:

```
SetCursorPos(100,100);
```

It's simple, but not working. Delphi gives me the error

```
 "statement expected,but expression of type 'longbool' found"
```

I am getting the same error with this command:

```
PostMessage(wb1.Handle,WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RIGHT,0);
```

where `wb1` is my `TWebBrowser` component.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add a uses for Windows ?

Comment: Alternatively to answer of Andreas you can set result of function to any boolean variable, for example "b := SetCursorPos(100,100);" where "b: boolean". But it is much better to enable Extended syntax feature like it is suggested in the answer.

Comment: The ideal thing is to write `if not SetCursorPos(...) then` and do some proper error handling. But even then, you might want "Extended syntax" for other reasons (I know of no reason *not* to use "Extended syntax").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have probably disabled a feature called "[Extended syntax](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Extended_syntax_%28Delphi%29)", which (among other things) allows you to use function calls like procedure calls. You can re-enable this feature in the project's options dialog.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Extended_syntax_%28Delphi%29 how this impact and how eto nable/disable it ?

Comment: Thank You! It worked for me. Project -> Options -> Compiler -> Extended syntax was unchecked.